# How to get date of all updates to particular table in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way to get all modification dates of a particular table in Oracle?

Query below:

```
select * from sys.dba_tab_modifications
```

could include number of inserts and updates however not particular dates of each.

Comment: I assume you have no columns like mod_ts (modification_timestamp)? Long story short, no. That'd be called Change Data Capture and Oracle sells that product

Comment: Are rowdependencies enabled?  If not then you get block level locking instead of row level and this wouldn't work.  If it is, you might be able to use [`ora_rowscn`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns007.htm)  and [`SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN)`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions142.htm#BABEHBCB) to get the date/time

Comment: Jacob, in that particular table there does not seem to be such.

xQber, rowdependencies are disabled, additionaly ORA: -08181 and -06512 are included in query result containing `SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN)` for at least one of the tables I could use it on.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use Oracle Flashback Query if you have sufficient privs, and sufficient redo logs exist for the time period in question:

```
select versions_operation
     , versions_starttime
     , versions_endtime
     , <TableAlias>.*
from <TableName> versions between timestamp systimestamp - numtodsinterval(1,'day')
                                        and systimestamp <TableAlias>
```

Comment: I used related query (TableName instead of aliases) and unfortunately values regarding versions columns seem to contain "(null)"

Comment: Values of null in the Versions_* columns indicates that the record was in the table longer than Oracle has retained history of modifications for the record.  Unless you setup the table with flashback archiving enabled, Oracle is only able to provide flashback data on the table for those records that has some DML operation stored in the current redo logs.  When the logs switch you lose access to the flashback info.